# Verifying files signed with openssl

Tags: openssl, cryptography

If I send a signed file with openssl to someone is it possible to verify the file without having the private key file?

I haven't send the private key to the other part.

After that files should be verified by the CA if the certificate is revoked and if when the certificate revoked?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Information Security Stack Exchange](http://security.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306).

Answer (score 0):

To veryfy file signature you need public key, and remember, never send private key to other people, it's only for owner. Sorry that I'm not answering last question, but it's little bit ununderstable.

Comment: It keep on saying verification failed

Comment: Provide more informations, what functions that you are using, give code snippet, I have not enough informations

Comment: First I signed the file 
`openssl rsautl -sign -in msg1 -inkey newkey.pem -out msg1.firma`
After I try to extract the pubkey from the certificate 
`openssl x509 -in newcert.pem -pubkey -noout > pubkey.pem`
And after when I try to verify the file I get verification failed
`openssl dgst -verify pubkey.pem -signature msg1.firma msg1`
`Verification Failure`

Comment: Thank you anyway but i was missing a command.. 

`openssl rsautl -verify -in msg1.firma -certin -inkey newcert.pem`